# Where to install sample data with a debian package

Tags: software-installation, permissions, dpkg

I'm currently porting a Windows application to Linux which has a set of sample data (images, configurations, source code, etc.) that can be used and changed by the user. To allow the user to actually modify the data, I would like to put it in a location where he is allowed to that. Also future users that will be added to the system should be allowed to modify the data without changing the permissions or anything like that.

On Windows there is a `C:\Users\Public\` folder where each user can read from and write to. I did a bit of research, and the best option for Linux seems to be the `/srv` folder, however I never heard of that folder and maybe there are better options.

The application is packaged in a debian package and currently installs to `/opt/<MyApplication>` and this is also the location where the sample data is currently put to, however with `root` as the owner. Should I put the sample data in the current users folder (something like `~/.<MyApplication>/sample_data`)? I could also just change the permissions of the `/opt/<MyApplication>` folder, but this sound like a bad idea to me.

Maybe someone knows what the best equivalent for Windows'  Public folder on Linux?

Comment: deb packages should not install to /opt. Debian will reject the package for that. Shared modifiable data should go in /var/run/<application_name> or /run/<application_name> (they are the same location). I don't see how this question is related to Ubuntu - seems like a Unix and Linux SE question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I put the data to lets say /var/run/<application_name>, what would be the best permissions for that folder to allow all users reading and writing on the data, and who should be the owner of that folder? By default the owner will be root when installed using `apt` but I could change the owner in a post installation script somehow.